# How to shorten import path

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a React-Redux app now. And a question appeared in my mind. I often have to write such strings like:

```
import * as mainActions from '../../../main/actions/main-actions';
import {wysiwygComponent} from '../../../../components.jsx';
```

So I'm kind of sick of these "../../..". Is there any way to make components having global names or paths?

Comment: I found a tutorial using webpack http://moduscreate.com/es6-es2015-import-no-relative-path-webpack/

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript itself but with the module loader/bundler you are using (if any). So, what are you using? As far as JavaScript, the language, is concerned, the module identifier is completely opaque.

Answer (score 0):

This is when [module loaders](https://appendto.com/2016/06/the-short-history-of-javascript-module-loaders/) come in handy.

If you use Webpack 2.x, you can modify the **Path Resolver Configuration** like this

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve('./client'),
    path.resolve('./node_modules')
  ]
},
```

You specify a number of directories in **modules** which will turn

```
import Header from '../../components/Header';
import TransactionForm from '../TransactionForm';
```

into

```
import Header from 'components/Header';
import TransactionForm from 'TransactionForm';
```

**Reference**: [No Relative Path](http://moduscreate.com/es6-es2015-import-no-relative-path-webpack/)